# fread - read all columns as character

Tags: r, data.table, fread, read.csv

I'm trying to read a file into R using `data.table` / `fread`.  Some of the fields have leading zeros and I just want to read the data in as characters and manually fix them.  However I can't figure out how to convey this to `fread`.  I'm trying this and it's assigning char, num, etc types as it normally would :

```
prop1 <- data.frame(fread("C:\\myFile.csv"), stringsAsFactors = F, colClasses = c(rep('character',58)))
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your `colClasses` argument is in the wrong place. It needs to be inside `fread()`, not inside `data.frame()`. Try this:

```
prop1 <- data.frame(fread("C:\\myFile.csv", 
                          colClasses = c(rep("character", 58))),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

More canonical use of `data.table` to accomplish this would be:

```
prop1 <- fread("C:\\myfile.csv", colClasses = 'character', data.table = FALSE)
```

Comment: @MichaelChirico how would I specify the class for one column and then just let fread automatically guess the classes for the remaining columns?

Comment: @user2205916 Use `colClasses = list(character = 'known_char_col')`, i.e., pass the known column's type in the `list` format, see `?fread`

Comment: @MichaelChirico I don't understand. My question, posed more clearly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48838222/r-data-tablefread

Answer (score 9):

simply put:

```
colClasses=c("character")
```

Comment: I know you are trying to be simple ,,, but some extra text will help people to consider it as complete answer :)  prop1 <- fread("C:\\myfile.csv", colClasses = 'character', data.table = FALSE)