# data.table::fread an `integer64` type, manually override colClass for only one column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a .csv where a column of IDs contains a long integer with leading zeros. `fread` converts it into an `integer64` type. How would I specify the class for one column and then just let `fread` automatically guess the classes for the remaining columns? Not sure if this is an "all-or-nothing" type of situation.

I have 50+ columns and would rather not have to specify the data types for all of them just because I have to do so for one of them.

My question is related to: [R fread - read all columns as character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44190450/r-fread-read-all-columns-as-character).

Comment: What type do you want the IDs column to be ?

Comment: Whatever type preserves the fidelity of a number like, "001001001150000285723". So I guess character?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `?fread`:

```
# colClasses
data = "A,B,C,D\n1,3,5,7\n2,4,6,8\n"
fread(data, colClasses=c(B="character",C="character",D="character"))  # as read.csv
fread(data, colClasses=list(character=c("B","C","D")))    # saves typing
fread(data, colClasses=list(character=2:4))     # same using column numbers
```

That is, if your zero-padded column is called `big_num`, just use `colClasses = list(character = 'big_num')`

Answer (score 3):

Addressing the auto detection and overriding a specific column:

```
# Auto detect the column types (special case of using nrows=0)
colCls <- sapply(fread(fName, nrows=0), class)
# Override the "wrong" detected column types
colCls[c("field1", "field2")] <- "character"
dt<-fread(fName, colClasses = colCls)
```